# Dropbear sshd - Disabling root login

Tags: ssh, dropbear

I have Dropbear sshd running instead of openssh. Looks like there is /etc/ssh/ config dir full of files but they do not seem to be used by dropbear. I wanted to disable root login, anyone know how?

Answer (score 5):

Dropbear doesn't use any configuration file in `/etc`, only keys. Your `/etc/ssh` must belong to an installation of OpenSSH. You specify Dropbear's few configuration options on the command line, for example `-w` to disable root logins (see the `dropbear` man page).